# Can the same socket.io interface support traditional socket connection as well as websocket connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have to support a GPS devices that writes to a socket and at the same time websockets from suppose a mobile device. Can the same socket.io code support both of these?

Comment: socket.io doesn't support raw sockets, only websocket protocol is supported, which isn't stable yet.. other than that socket.io tries to achieve realtime using flashsocket, long-polling, and other.

Comment: Thanks. I found this link to be helpful https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec. Isn't there any module to implement plain tcp sockets in node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : **no such module for socket.io to call or serve TCP requests doesn't exist** .

Long answer : you can easily solve this in your node.js by working with this possible options

- First option would be to just support socket.io all the way client
  and server. So you can easily develop with one protocol.
- Second option is to combine socket.io + TCP server, and handle
  received requests with the same handler. To simplify take this as an
  example for server-side.

```
  // run socket.io server
    // run TCP server
    function Handler(event,data,socket){
     this.getProfileData=function(data,socket){
      // things to do 
      // call socket.emit for socket.io ,or socket.write for TCP
     }
     this[event](data,socket); // call appropriate event
    }
    // when receiving a new message from either socket.io or TCP
    new Handler(event,data,socket);
```

- Third option is to use a bridge such as [WebTCP](https://github.com/yankov/webtcp) or implement your own bridge.
- There is also experimental TCP socket API for browsers, but its not recommended.

Comment: Thanks again GeoPhoenix. You have given me a lot to chew upon. Will work upon these and see what works out best for me.